# Splitting street in Address table which participates in Relationship Class (1-M)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, splitting, relationship-class, error-000464

I have a table "Addresses" and the Feature "streets".
The feature "Streets" are lines.

I need to do a relation with this table with this feature. What I do?

I tried built a "relationship class". The type is "1-M". It is the line of a street with the table of a address. But happens an error. I can´t split the line of a street. Anyone knows how to fix it?

That is the error:
"

> The feature could not be split. The field is not nullable.

"

I found the error "`FDO_E_FIELD_NOT_NULLABLE`" description on a ESRI site. But they don't told how to fix it. This is the link:
http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/8.3/ComponentHelp/esriCore/fdoError.htm

I need the relationship and to split the streets!
How to solve/fix this error?

---

The real problem is: I have a Feature of streets, called "Eixos". And a Table of Addresses, called "Logradouros". I tried with Domains. But when I run a script python that make "Table to Domain" give me the error of "

> ERROR 000464: Cannot get exclusive schema lock

". But I cannot kill the other users. Do you know a good solution to do a relationship Feature Street vs Table Address?

Comment: The real problem is: I have a Feature of streets, called "Eixos". And a Table of Addresses, called "Logradouros".
I tried with Domains. But when I run a script python that make "Table to Domain" give me the error of "ERROR 000464: Cannot get exclusive schema lock". But I cannot kill the other users. Do you know a good solution to do a relationship Feature Street vs Table Address? Any tip? Pls!

Comment: Is this feature class in SDE?  Or is it a file GDB or a personal GDB?  Are there other users actually viewing this data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to obtain exclusive access to the data by getting the other users to close ArcMap temporarily.

It should then allow you to split the line.

Comment: Thanks Rayner. I think those are the only options.
But I still think ArcGIS is deficient. ArcMap should have a better way to relate a Layer with an Oracle table.
It should be like the relationship Genexus.